# Microsoft Graph API Get Group Events

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the MS Graph API (which I'm new at) to write a Powershell script to copy the events from a **private** group calendar into a **public** group calendar.

So far I've managed to get the private group using this call:

```
$api = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups"
$groups = $null
try { $groups = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($token.access_token)" } -Uri $api -Method "GET" -ContentType "application/json" }
catch { Write-host -Foreground Red $_}
$calendar_group = $groups.value | ? -Property mailNickname -eq $pvt_group
```

However, when I try and move this forth and get the events for that group, I get bounced on a **403 error.**

The calls I'm trying are either:

```
$api = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$group_ID/calendar/events"
Write-Host $api -Fore Green
$events = $null
try { $events = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($token.access_token)" } -Uri $api -Method "GET" -ContentType "application/json" }
    catch { Write-host -Foreground Red $_}
```

Or:

```
$api = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$group_ID/events"
Write-Host $api -Fore Green
$events = $null
try { $events = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($token.access_token)" } -Uri $api -Method "GET" -ContentType "application/json" }
catch { Write-host -Foreground Red $_}
```

Both fail on the same error.
NB: the $group_ID variable is correctly valued by the first call.

I've the app registered on Azure with the following permimssions:

1. Calendars.Read Delegated
2. Calendars.Read.Shared Delegated
3. Calendars.ReadWrite Delegated
4. Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Delegated
5. Directory.AccessAsUser.All Delegated
6. Directory.Read.All Delegated
7. Directory.Read.All Application
8. Directory.ReadWrite.All Delegated
9. Directory.ReadWrite.All Application
10. Group.Read.All Delegated
11. Group.Read.All Application
12. Group.ReadWrite.All Delegated
13. Group.ReadWrite.All Application
14. GroupMember.Read.All Delegated
15. GroupMember.Read.All Application
16. User.Read Delegated

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you copy paste the value of `$($token.access_token)` to https://jwt.ms and check the value in the `scp` element. Does it contain the Group.Read.All?

Comment: What I find very helpful for these situations is the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). Just mentioning it in case you haven't checked that one out.

Comment: hi @Melissa thanks for your input. It's all really new to me.
re: jwt.ms: there's no scp element. However in the roles section of the claim these are all listed: Group.Read.All,Directory.ReadWrite.All,Group.ReadWrite.All,Directory.Read.All,GroupMember.Read.All
re: Graph Explorer: I run the query there, I get the same error:
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
along with the suggestion:
Forbidden - 403 - 73ms. You need to consent to the permissions on the Modify permissions (Preview) tab
which I think I did already.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. I will try to investigate it today. By the way, is there a reason why you don't use the Az powershell modules?

Comment: @Melissa thanks for your time and effort. No specific reason, I guess I just started experimenting that way.

Answer (score 0):

The access token that you use, is an application access token (the permissions are defined under the `Roles` section). If a user access token is used, you will see the permissions under de `scp` section.

In the Microsoft docs ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)) it is stated that calling the /calendar/events unfortunately is not supported with an application access token.
[image: printscreen permissions]

If you assign your account to the `Groups administrator` role, you will implicitly be assigned the `Group.Read.All` permission. Then use the access token from your account to call the endpoint without any issues (because you've already granted the needed permissions for delegation in the App Registration).

Comment: Thanks. 
My account is GA on that tenant. I added the Groups Administrator role to it (not sure if it was needed), then I removed the Application permissions from the app, but it's still not working, so I guess the error is now in how I obtain the token. 
As you pointed out I'm getting an application access token, whereas I need a user one.

Comment: To get a user token, you should have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow). There you can also find a link to the postman collection containing all different scenarios for requesting tokens. 
I do recommend using the az cli (`az login`) or the az powershell modules (`Login-AzAccount`) because those are available to make life a bit easier :)